# Should I use the Workbench Access module to implement the workflow we have in mind?

Tags: 7, workflows, workbench

I am new to Drupal altogether and have a question about a site i was asked to work on. We think that [Workbench Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_access) will solve our problem but we have not yet figured out how to make it work the way we want.

I have a large site and I have the users setup, and Roles setup, etc. But what I want to do is let users edit submit edits (for approval) on only one portion of the site (the staff portion to edit/update their own info). I also want an email to be sent (to me) for letting me know they submitted a "needs review" request if possible.

I know this might be a lot to go over but I would really love any help or a good walk through for this.

Comment: I'm not sure about Workbench Access but with Drupal it seems that your requirement is basic. Have you looked at permissions and Rules? Drupal has fine-grain permissions and Rules will help you fire-up emails on triggers.

Comment: i heard about that. If that would work i could try that. Where might i locate those permissions?

Comment: For starters you can look at 'People' from the administration menu and go to 'Permissions' Tab. This is role-based permissions. You can create additional roles too.

Answer (score 0):

The [Workbench Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_access) module seems to only partially cover your needs. 
If it was up to me to implement a solution for the challenge you're trying to solve, I'd go for another approach, as further detailed below.

Have a look at my answers to either of these questions:

- [How to implement a multi step approval with webforms/entityforms based on form components?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164601/how-to-implement-a-multi-step-approval-with-webforms-entityforms-based-on-form-c/164607#164607)
- [How can I allow anonymous visitors to submit content?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164199/how-to-implement-content-suggestions-by-anonymous-users)

These answers explain how you can implement a workflow that is pretty (though not exactly) similar to what you are looking for.

To do so, it "only" requires you to use these modules (and regular content types):

- [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).
- [Node Convert](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_convert).
- [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag).
- [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access).

And by using such approach, it does not require modules like "[Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform)" or "[Workbench](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench)" (modules that are typically involved for these kinds of workfows).