# How to build a simple content approval workflow between an administrator and a user?

Tags: webforms, workbench

I have the following requirement on a Drupal site.

**User interface** (Authenticated user):

1. A simple form with some text fields
2. Radio buttons to select the content type
3. A submit button to submit the form

An authenticated user has to submit a form which will have few text fields and a content type selection.

**User interface** (Administrator):

1. A grid to see all the submissions.
2. A column with two buttons beside every submission "Review" and "Send back".

Once submitted the form, admin will be able to the submission, they may either review the content or send back the content to the user.

When clicked on review button, the page has to take to "Add content" page with title, description, attachment and other fields pre-filled.

When sent back, user will be notified and they may review the content and resubmit the form.

I achieved this requirement using [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module which captures the user submission and written a custom module to fetch the webform submission content and creates a node based on the submission. I have yet to work on the "sent back to the user" part.

I'm wondering, if there is any simple way of doing this workflow.

P.S: I have already tried [Workbench](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench) but I'm looking for a simple workflow where a non-technical guy (administrator) could easily get it.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Sorry for the late response, I have achieved this requirement using Webform, Webform Rules, Webform Workflow and custom hooks.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at my answer to "[How to implement a multi step approval with webforms/entityforms based on form components?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164601/how-to-implement-a-multi-step-approval-with-webforms-entityforms-based-on-form-c/164607#164607)". It explains how you can implement a workflow that is pretty (though not exactly) similar to what you are looking for.

To do so, it "only" requires you to use these modules (and regular content types):

- [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).
- [Node Convert](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_convert).
- [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag).
- [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access).

Use such approach, it does not require modules like "[Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform)" or "[Workbench](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench)".

Answer (score 2):

Another workbench alternative is....

[CPS](https://www.drupal.org/project/cps), some details about it (from its project page):

> CPS, or the Content Publishing System, is a radical way of handling
>   revisions for entities. It takes total control over revision
>   management for all supported entities. For CPS-enabled entities, the
>   revision tab is completely replaced and users are not allowed to
>   manually create or move around revisions.

If CPS still very complex for you, you might look into build your custom workflow using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).

Comment: Is there any tutorial to make this workflow work? Also, can you tell me what contributed modules do I need to use to achieve this along with rules module?

Comment: I personally have never build it myself with Rules. However, I have seem website that have a great workflow with Rules. And is very scalable because Rules is base on Drupal functionality. I will recommend start with Rules and base on what you need you will keep searching for Rules sub-modules.