# Create a custom form in Drupal CMS for editors

Tags: 7, forms

I need to create a form for our Drupal Editors. The form must allow them to add records to database.

I see next steps to do:

1. I add action in place I want.
2. User clicks on action and modal form appears (that's I do not know how to do in Drupal way).
3. User submits form and record is added to database.
4. If possible refresh current page so user can see new record.

Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

So far I'm looking on: [CTools Auto-modal](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools_automodal) and [CTools Auto-modal Admin Interface](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools_automodal_admin). However I'm not sure if that is right direction.

Comment: The right direction is looking at form [examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples)

Comment: If you're in D7, it's probably easier to use the [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module [How to Build a Drupal 7 Webform](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwlJgrvT1Kk)

Comment: What's so special about those "records to be added to the database"? And as yet another alternative to @NoSssweat 's comment: how about using an approach similar to my answer to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164601 ? PS: which version of Drupal?

Comment: @pierre.Vriens I'm using D7. I will have a look on your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: @DmytroPastovenskyi : Thanks for the comment. But what about this: ***What's so special about those "records to be added to the database"?***

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens nothing special :) I just meant I want to specify programatically where exactly goes my record (specific table etc).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use a regular content type, add whatever fields you'd need, and let your Drupal editors edit regular nodes.

As a variation, use the [ECK](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) module so that you have custom entities (instead of nodes). And then let Drupal take care of storing the data in an appropriate table in the database. With such approach you get all sorts of extra facilities (integrations with other modules), out-of-the-Drupal-box ... [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group), [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag), you name it.

Another approach could be like I described in my answer to "[How to implement a multi step approval with webforms/entityforms based on form components?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164601)".