# How can I set up Drupal so people can collaborate on content development prior to making it public

Tags: 7

I have a small website which, from a modules perspective, I want to keep as simple as possible.

Apart from displaying content, a main purpose of the site is to facilitate collaborative authoring and publishing of: articles, product updates and case studies.

To achieve this I would like individual contributors to be able to create & edit content prior to public release (just to be clear, I'm not looking for concurrent editing here).

This seemingly simple requirement leaves me stumped because unpublished content seems unavailable for further editing by the original creator, let alone co-collaborators.

Similarly, some items of content will need periodic updating. To achieve this I expect they will need to be reviewed, updated & debated offline, but in a way that leaves the current version public.  The update process needs to allow multiple authors to edit in private prior to republishing / making the updated content public.

I'm at a loss as to how this is most easily achieved - would appreciate any advise that leads to a simple solution.

Comment: I think I need to take a closer look at 'views'...

Comment: Hi everyone - thank you for your help.  I managed to get the furthest by following the proposed answer from @mpdonadio but confess Drupal ended up getting the better of me and I have moved my site over to WordPress....  At this stage I'm left with the overall impression that Drupal is amazingly powerful but too much power in my hands ;-) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The near defacto-standard for this in Drupal 7 is the [Workbench Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) module, which is part of the broader [Workbench](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench) suite.  From the module page:

> Workbench Moderation adds arbitrary moderation states to Drupal core's
>   "unpublished" and "published" node states, and affects the behavior of
>   node revisions when nodes are published. Moderation states are tracked
>   per-revision; rather than moderating nodes, Workbench Moderation
>   moderates revisions.

and about Workbench in general:

> Workbench is a suite of modules which provide easier content
>   management for content administrators. Each of the "Workbench" modules
>   has been tested to work with the main Workbench module, and with the
>   other modules in the Workbench suite. The Workbench suite is modular,
>   allowing site builders to build the workflow that best suits the
>   content administrators on their site. The Workbench suite provides
>   authors, editors, and publishers with a unified interface for managing
>   content relevant to them. It allows people to focus on content, rather
>   than on learning Drupal.

This is highly tailorable to your particular organization, and all organizations differ.  You didn't list out a lot of additional requirements, but typically you would create roles (Author, Editor, Publisher, Admin), and then define which role can do what (eg, Authors can only edit their own content, Editors can edit all, but only Publishers can make nodes public).  Additional controls can be implemented with [Workbench Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_access).

I have deployed solutions based on this for many organizations, mostly with success.  I also like this solution, compared to others, as this module suite is "site-builder friendly".  This means, that I can get the basics going for a site, and then have non-developers on the team work with clients to tailor it for their needs.

When it doesn't work well, it is usually because the organization doesn't really *want* content workflows as opposed to *needing* them.

This solution is also providing the base for the [Content Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2757719) initiative for Drupal 8.

That said, depending on your situtation Groups / Organic Groups may be a better fit (as described in another answer).  I would take both solutions for a test drive to see what works best for you.

Comment: What do you mean with Group**s** (in your last paragraph)? Maybe the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module ?

Comment: @mpdonadio thank you I will take a look at Workbench and post back.

Comment: WorkBench Moderation looks good.  I have installed locally and seems to been what I need.  I still have a difficulty whereby regular users are unable to return to their own (or other) unpublished content.  Not sure how to add the menu link.  Will keep looking but have to stop for a while.  Thanks

Comment: OK... I managed to get workbench moderation working on a test site, and it seems to do exactly what I want.  I used Views to expose parts of the interface to authorized roles.  When I attempted replicate on my production website it failed, probably because there are too many other modules? I think I need to restart my production website from scratch :-(

Answer (score 0):

A commonly suggested solution for this often *starts* with using the [Workbench Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) module. However, IMO only using that module is often not sufficient to address things such as "collaboration" (as in your question). Read on for some other options that are available using existing modules which integrate pretty well with each other.

#### Option 1

Have a look at my answer to "[How to implement a multi step approval with webforms/entityforms based on form components?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164601/how-to-implement-a-multi-step-approval-with-webforms-entityforms-based-on-form-c/164607#164607)". It explains how you can implement a workflow that is pretty (though not exactly) similar to what you are looking for.

To do so, it "only" requires you to use these modules (and regular content types):

- [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).
- [Node Convert](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_convert).
- [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag).
- [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access).

#### Option 2

Another alternative you may want to consider (or combine with the previous approach) is to start using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module, which allows for creating arbitrary collections of your content and users on your site, and grant access control permissions on those collections.

[Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) is available as of D7, and has a D8 version also. It is designed to be an alternative to [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og). The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable.

For more details about the various types of roles used by the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module, refer to my answer to "[What are the various roles supported by the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197493)".

Resources:

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".

Comment: Thank you - I will have a look and report back.  Unfortunately I have to step out for a while.  Re Groups - I have installed the Group module on a clean test site already so hope to make some sense of that soon.

Comment: @SlowLearner good for you you already have the Group module ... you may also want to review the questions using the group-tag.

Comment: @SlowLearner : I wonder why you added the "group" tag to your question now ... there is (still) nothing in your question that indicates your question is related to that module. IMO you should remove that tag again.

Comment: My apologies, I thought I was following your suggestion

Comment: Throwing together a bunch of overly-bloated modules that were never meant to be integrated, to solve a problem that has already been solved perfectly by a purpose-written module, is a very poor suggestion. As usual I don't even see an answer here, just links to your own, never anyone else's, answers on other tangentially related questions, and some mindless filler to avoid the quality filters. Very, very poor.

Comment: I have to admit, I find it astonishing that setting up collaborative authoring is so difficult... WorkBench moderation works and Views definitely helped me get close to what I want.  I'll need to read your other article again and work through the steps properly.  Thanks